# bash variable with double-quotes

Tags: bash

There is an exported env-variable `X`:

```
X="-t \"2 2.1\""
```

The following command is parsed wrong when using this variable:

```
yarn jest $X
```

```
yarn jest -t '"2' '2.1"'
```

Instead of:

```
yarn jest -t "2 2.1"
```

---

I have read a-lot of similar questions but none of them worked. Any help?

Comment: The variable expands as expected: `-t "2 2.1"`. You have an error in the code that you don't show.

Comment: @Maxim those quotes aren't syntactical, though, they're just part of two separate strings as shown in the question.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the question. there is no error on my mac.

Comment: @StavAlfi You need to add code that reproduces the issue. `X="-t \"2 2.1\"" echo yarn jest $X` doesn't reproduce what you observe.

Comment: running `X="-t \"2 2.1\""` and then `yarn jest $X` will reproduce the problem in osx.

Comment: @Maxim it _does_ reproduce the issue: the problem isn't that the quotes aren't shown in the output of your test case; it is that they are no longer interpreted by the shell as syntax, they are just a character like any other, so `yarn` is passed two arguments instead of one.

Comment: @StavAlfi some recommended reading (the site is very helpful in general) https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @TomFenech You are probably right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using shell array for this:

```
arr=('-t' '2 2.1')
```

then use it as:

```
yarn jest "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: the parsing will be `-t '2 2.1'` and not `-t "2 2.1"` but it is ok for me.

Comment: @StavAlfi: it is essentially. same. You can have array as: `arr=("-t" "2 2.1")` also.

Comment: @StavAlfi : Both All of  `'2 2.1'`, `"2 2.1"` and `2\ 2.1` denote the exactly same 5-character string (consisting of 2, space, 2, period and 1). Where do you see any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `X="-t '2 2.1'"`

Use single quotes inside double quotes instead of using double quotes twice.

Hope this helps